# Configuring Linux Mint as a Gateway

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, routing, iproute

My trusty Slackware box died, and I had to replace it with an already built Linux Mint v18. I was hoping this would be a drop-in replacement, but routing has changed over the years with iproute2. I was hoping just adding "route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eth1" would work - and it does - but the issue is my gateway computer can't establish a connection to anything on eth0.

Simplified layout:

```
|192.168.0.0/24|---|Gateway|---|192.168.1.0/24|
                                     |
                                     ---|ROUTER 192.168.1.1|---|Internet|
```

The Gateway has eth0, and eth1, and is a firewall for everything on 192.168.0.0/24. The router generally handles WiFi devices on 192.168.1.0/24.

Current configuration, I let KDE network manager bring up the interfaces, and just added the gw command as stated above:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
```

This is working; all devices on 192.168.0.0/24 are routed properly, and I can connect to the gateway from 192.168.1.0/24 and the internet without issue.

However, I can't initiate so much as a ping from the gateway to anything on 192.168.0.0/24. I ran tcpdump, and found the source IP was changed to 192.168.1.2 (eth1). So this tells me the packets are going out the wrong interface, even though I set the metric for the gateway line to be higher than the others, and therefore not considered first.

I've read a number of stackexchange posts, and a few sites such as [policy routing](http://www.policyrouting.org/PolicyRoutingBook/ONLINE/CH05.web.html), and [linux-ip](http://linux-ip.net/linux-ip/tools-ip-route.html#ex-tools-ip-route-nat-network), but I just can't seem to find a solution.

I'm not terribly familiar with iproute2, but what I've been able to pull together, just to get 192.168.0.0/24 working is:

```
echo "1 admin" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/24 priority 1 table admin
ip rule add to 192.168.0.0/24 priority 1 table admin
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 table admin dev eth0
ip route cache flush
```

This makes sense to me; create a table which has higher priority than the defaults, create a rule from/to, then add a route on the same table to send it over eth0. But, this is not working.

It seems like there is something I'm missing, but I can't find it.

```
# uname -a
Linux neXuss2 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: When the packets for `eth0` go to the wrong interface, you should only see them on `eth1` with the tcpdump parameter `-i eth1`. If they go out to the correct interface, then the routing table of the clients in network `192.168.0.8/24` may hold an incorrect routing entry for the network `192.168.1.0/24`. Ip forwarding must be enabled anyway, as @telcoM stated in his answer.

Comment: I see, this is a very old question. Is it still active?

Comment: @gerhardd. Define "active"! You can see answers, comments, and you can see whether any answer had been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need `iproute2` for such a simple case.

However, you should check that the master switch for IP routing is on: make sure your `/etc/sysctl.conf` includes the line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and then run `sudo sysctl -p` to make it take effect immediately.

The default value for `net.ipv4.ip_forward` sysctl is 0, which disables all IPv4 routing functionality completely.

Also, you should check the basics: verify that the eth0 interface actually has a link and is not producing errors. `ethtool eth0` to verify link state and `ethtool -S eth0` to view the statistics counters in the NIC driver.

Comment: That was disabled, I enabled it, and ran sysctl, but it had no effect. Routing from eth0 to eth1 is working, but talking to computers on eth0 is not. Ethtool shows no errors.